# i want to do something when i close console VB window is that possible?

Tags: .net, vb.net, console

I want to call function or execute some code when i `close` the window in console vb is that possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yeap it's possible if you believe in yourself... and ofcourse if you _tried_ something.

Comment: i tried to do it before i come here but there is no event when close the console application and i did search on google but i did not find any solution. So please if you cant help cuz you dont know how, don't post answer like that cuz its reflect how much you are horrible.

Comment: I agree with Crush, I must be possible...

Comment: @mohammed, Look, I don't want to have an argument with you (since I cannot understand some of what you are saying because of bad grammars). SO is not for the lazies. So like what you've said.. if you _TRIED_ something, you can include it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I haven't tested it as such, i'll leave that up to you :) however this should lead you on the right direction :)

```
Module Module1
Public Enum ConsoleEvent
    CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2
End Enum
Private Declare Function SetConsoleCtrlHandler Lib "kernel32" (ByVal handlerRoutine As ConsoleEventDelegate, ByVal add As Boolean) As Boolean
Public Delegate Function ConsoleEventDelegate(ByVal MyEvent As ConsoleEvent) As Boolean
Private handler As ConsoleEventDelegate

Sub Main()
    handler = AddressOf Application_ConsoleEvent
    If Not SetConsoleCtrlHandler(handler, True) Then
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR ADDING HANDLER")
    Else
        ''ADD YOUR MAIN CODE HERE.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello WORLD!")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End If
End Sub
Public Function Application_ConsoleEvent(ByVal [event] As ConsoleEvent) As Boolean
    Dim cancel As Boolean = False
    Select Case [event]
        Case ConsoleEvent.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT
            'ADD YOUR CLOSING CODE WITHIN HERE, you dont need to have the Msgbox, its just there so you can understand :)
            MsgBox("Program being closed!")
            ''ADD your clean up code if needed here.
    End Select

    Return cancel ' handling the event.
End Function
End Module
```

Let me know how you go :)

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what i wanted to do

Comment: No worries mate, happy to help :)